# Chrome: Save cached files

Tags: google-chrome

I can view cache list by `chrome://cache` in Chrome. However I can only get a hex view of the file. How can I save/export it? (Currently I can only search it manually in `~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome`)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows systems, [I use ChromeCacheView](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/chrome/ChromeCacheView/) by Nir Sofer at [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/). You can right-click on an item it displays in the Chrome cache and choose "Save Selected Items" or choose to open an item in a browser from the ChromeCacheView **File** menu.

If you want to view the contents from your OS X system, though, if the contents of the file aren't confidential you could use copy and paste into [Viewing Chrome cache (the easy way)](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html) or use the [Via saved cache file](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html) method there to upload a file to the site.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, open a new tab and navigate to chrome://cache/
Click on whichever file you want to view.
You should then see a page with a bunch of text and numbers.
Copy all the text on that page.
Paste it.