# How can I get my browser to persist its cache forever?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cache

When I visit a web page, it is often cached by my web browser (Chrome). If I click on a link and then click "back" then the cached version is shown.

But if I close the tab or browser and then return to the same page, it doesn't use the cache. I want it to ALWAYS use the cache.

Also, whether or not a websites resources are saved in my browser's cache is at the mercy of the server's response headers. It's standard practice to mark HTML files as "do not cache" which gives publishers complete control, but makes it more difficult to cache full pages.

Is it possible to configure Chrome (or another browser) to NOT expire the cache until I manually decide? I want to change Chrome's rules for when it expires the cache, and to ignore any response headers indicating that the cache should expire.

What sort of things would a userscript or other software need to implement to achieve this?

UDPATE: This is not at all the same as [Chrome: Save cached files](https://superuser.com/questions/1027344/chrome-save-cached-files). If the server responded with a "do not cache" header then the files you need won't be there. Also selecting individual files out of a list to view them, or using a separate application to view cached pages is quite different to viewing a complete cached page in the original browser in a manner identical to viewing the live page. Think about it: Every page you view in a web browser has *already* been downloaded from the server, the only thing that needs to be changed is whether or not it's cached for *subsequent* requests, and *when* that cache is invalidated. Those two variables should be firmly under user control.

UPDATE 2: Of course there are several ways to save web pages that have been downloaded, and view them later. I could use the File | Save As feature, or I could print them out on paper. My question is specifically about configuring the web browser's existing cache(s) for this purpose. This is an important distinction because the browser cache is probably the most *efficient* way to store web assets as that is its actual purpose.

Comment: That's what WayBack Machine is for ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome and Edge, there are only settings for what to clear, none for how long to keep it.

Surprising to some perhaps, I have learned to measure time in decades. Forever is a very long time.

Having a browser keep cache until you are finished with that computer or until you decide to clear cache is just not practical and not provided for in major browsers. (Not even to mention the possible impact on disk space).